# Buscar por fecha model find mongoose no funciona

Tags: nodejs, date, mongoose

Estoy tratando de buscar x objetos por fecha,(la recibo de un formulario , se que me llega en formato UTC hs antes de la real),hago lo siguiente.

Primero creo el objeto

```
console.log(datos) // Contiene los datos correctos , fecha ,datos ,etc

Evento.create(datos,(err,evento)=>{
    if(err)console.log("Error");
    else{
        console.log("Eventro creado",evento);
                        Task.create({
                            fecha:datos.fecha,
              cron: {
                enabled: true,
                startAt: datos.fecha,
                interval: '40 * * * * *' 
              }
            });


        User.update({_id:datos.creador},{$push:{eventos:evento._id}},{},(err,user)=>{
            if(err)console.log(err);
            else{
                console.log("Usuario actualizado");
                console.log(user);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Reviso en la bd , y efectivamente , se creo dicho evento con la fecha correspondiente , pero luego ahi mismo mas abajo trato de buscar

```
console.log("Buscaremos el evento x por fecha");
Evento.find({fecha:datos.fecha},(err,ev)=>{
    console.log("Estos son los eventos encontrados",ev);
})
```

y me sale ev=[], habiendo un evento que coincide con la fecha dado , ya revise y las fechas son iguales , ¿Que podría estar pasando?

Answer (score 1):

Bueno encontré la solución , veo que era porque cuando creo el modelo en mongo , este almacena la fecha en formato ISO ,asi que solo había que usar datos.fecha.toISOString(), para comparar las fechas.